# How do I find items in one collection that match items in another collection using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two generic collections:

```
List<Model> listA
List<Model> listB

puclic class Model 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

How can I compare Id's of two collections using LINQ, and if  `Id` in the `listB` equals `Id` in the `listA` set `IsFavorite` property of the `listA` is `true` and return changed `listA` collection.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried and how it failed?

Comment: Why not try a simple loop first and afterwards try to implement a shorter version using Linq? This way you also get a better understanding on what Linq actually does (spoiler: it´s no magic, it´s just some loops as well).

Comment: LINQ for mutating the properties of list items just doesn't make a whole load of sense. Nor does "return changed listA collection" - as the listA won't have changed at all - it will have the same items in it as when you started (albeit with some changed property values)

Comment: I agree Jamiec, Modifying elements in a collection isn´t what LINQ is designed for (the "q" stands for **query**). You should just write a simple loop and update the values there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking to something similar to this

```
foreach (var model in listA)
{
   if(listB.Any(x=> x.Id == model.Id))
   {
        model.IsFavorite = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

```
from aItem in listA 
            join bItem in ListB on aItem.id equals bItem.Id
            select new Model{ isFavorable = true, ....};
```